# Is a function absolutely continuous if and only if its derivative is in $L^1$?

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

So I was reading about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue Integrals. It said $F$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ iff $F'$ exists $a.e.$, $F'\in L^1$ and $$F(x)-F(a)=\int_a^x F'dm.$$
Well, but the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Riemann Integrals we know that if $F$ is differentiable everywhere, then $$F(x)-F(a)=\int_a^xF'(x)dx.$$
Given that the Riemann Integral, when it exists, equals the Lebesgue integral for $L^1$ functions, would this mean that if $F$ is not absolutely continuous, would I be correct in concluding that $F'\not\in L^1.$ In particular, at least one of 
$$\int_a^b (F')^+dm,$$
$$\int_a^x(F')^-dm$$
was infinite.

Comment: @Gae.S. thank you.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus for Riemann integral says that if $F$ has a Riemann-integrable derivative on $[a,b]$, then $F(x)=F(a)+\int_a^x F'(x)\,dx$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. There are differentiable functions with non-Riemann-integrable derivative.

Comment: If you are curious, I expand on what @Gae.S. mentioned in my undergrad thesis here https://arminda.whitman.edu/theses/341

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. What *is* true is that $F$ is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions) if and only if it has a derivative almost everywhere, this derivative is in $L^1$, *and* $F(x)-F(a)=\int_a^xF'(x)dx$. However, the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) also has a derivative almost everywhere (except at $0$), which is $0$, and hence in $L^1$, but it is not absolutely, or even just, continuous. Neither is the [Cantor's staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), which is even continuous with $F'=0$ a.e. So $\int_a^b (F')^\pm\,dm$ need not be infinite for absolute continuity of $F$ to fail.

Almost everywhere is just a wrong notion of the derivative for such functions. One can define the derivative in a more general, [distributional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Derivatives_of_distributions), sense. In that sense the derivative of the Heaviside function is the $\delta$-function, and the derivative of the [Cantor's staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a  [singular continuous measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_measure). If we take $F'$ in *this* sense it will be true that it is in $L^1$ if and only if $F$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: I wonder if we let $f$ be a continuous function and it has a derivative almost everywhere, and the derivative is also in $L^1$, then can we conclude that $f$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: @Yanyu No. As mentioned in the post, Cantor's staircase is a counterexample. By the [Lebesgue's decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem#Refinement), to get absolute continuity you need to exclude singular continuous measures in the distributional derivative. Continuity with derivative almost everywhere being in $L^1$ does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

### Correction

If a differentiable function $f$ is continuously differentiable except a measure-zero set of points on a closed interval, then Newton-Leibniz formula holds for $f$.
There is a function called *Volterra's function* differentiable everywhere, having a bounded derivative but its derivative is not Riemann integrable.

### Answer

If you assume the differentibility of $f$ on the whole closed interval, then the answer is positive.

In fact, we have the following conclusion.

If $f$ is a continuous function of differentibility except countable points on closed interval $[a,b]$, then following conditions are equivalent:
(1) Newton-Leibniz formula holds for $f$ and $f'$ on every subinterval of $[a,b]$ in the sense of Lebesgue integral.
(2) $f$ is of absolute continuity.
(3) $f$ is of bounded variation.
(4) $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Reference: J. Yeh, *Real Analysis Theory of Measure and Integration*, pp. 272-274.

---

### Puzzlement

If we denote the set of absolutely continuous functions by $AC[a,b]$, the set of functions of bounded variation by $BV[a,b]$, the set of continuous functions which are differentiable except countable points on $[a,b]$ by $ D^{ec}[a,b] $, and the set of functions a.e. differentiable whose derivatives are included in $L^1[a,b]$ by $L^{1,1}[a,b]$.

It is clear that $BV[a,b]\cap D^{ec}[a,b]=L^{1,1}[a,b]\cap D^{ec}[a,b]=AC[a,b]\cap D^{ec}[a,b]$.
I wonder if $AC[a,b]\subseteq D^{ec}[a,b]$. If true, we have $L^{1,1}[a,b]\cap D^{ec}[a,b]=AC[a,b]$, that is amazing. Or could we construct an absolutely continuous function undifferentiable on an uncountable set?